# Column XXXXX' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEXel.png) query is in the ColdFusion, and it can be run for the old version ColdFusion, but can't run this query right now. Just reminds me Column "TUser.LastName" is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

```
     <CFQUERY name="getUserList" datasource="#REQUEST.dsn#" maxrows="1">
        SELECT 
            TUser.userID as user_ID,
            Min(TUser.agencyID) as agencyID,
            Min(TUser.servicing_EntityID) as servicing_EntityID,
            Min(Tuser.userid) AS userID, 
            Min(Tuser.lastname) AS lastName, 
            Min(Tuser.firstname) AS firstName, 
            Min(Tuser.isSecondary) AS isSecondary, 
            Min(Tuser.corporate_ID) AS corporate_ID, 
            Min(Tuser.city) AS city, 
            Min(TUser.address1) AS address1,
            Min(Corporate_Client.client_name) AS client_name, 
            Min(TLocationProvState.abrev) AS abrev, 
            TUser_Loyalty.loyalty_ID AS loyalty_ID
        FROM TUser
        LEFT JOIN TLocationProvState ON (Tuser.provinceID = TLocationProvState.PROVSTATEID)
        LEFT JOIN Corporate_Client ON (Tuser.corporate_ID = Corporate_Client.client_ID)
        LEFT JOIN TUser_Loyalty ON (Tuser.userid = TUser_Loyalty.userID)
        LEFT JOIN TLoyalty ON (TUser_Loyalty.loyalty_ID = TLoyalty.loyalty_ID)
        WHERE (0=1)
        GROUP BY TUser.UserID, TUser_Loyalty.loyalty_ID
        ORDER BY TUser.LastName, TUser.FirstName, TUser.User_ID
        </CFQUERY>
```

Comment: change your ORDER BY to `ORDER BY LastName,  firstName, User_ID`  you'll note you have Min(LastName) and min(FirstName) in your select which is different than the result of the Min.  Since the table alias are available in the order by, just use the column alias.

Comment: Tried....it didn't work, still the same error. And now the sql is GROUP BY TUser.UserID, TUser_Loyalty.loyalty_ID, TUser.LastName, TUser.FirstName
  ORDER BY user_ID, loyalty_ID, lastName, firstName

Comment: When I have odd behavior I just keep breaking down the query... Eliminate the order by and only use `TUser.userID, Tuser_Loyalty.Loyalty_ID in the group by does it work then?  If it runs then the order by is the problem and we focus there, if it still doesn't run eliminate the mins and group by. Does it run then, then add back in one min and the group by...

Comment: I bet this query could be done with a DISTINCT and no grouping. Everything is tied to the user so the same values will come back for all LoyaltyID's.

Comment: I added DISTINCT and commented out the Group by. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to `ORDER` by fields that have not been designated as group fields. The fields will have to be returned in order to order by, therefore, the Query Executor needs to know how to handle all fields in a grouped statement.

```
GROUP BY TUser.UserID, TUser_Loyalty.loyalty_ID, TUser.LastName, TUser.FirstName
ORDER BY TUser.User_ID, TUser.LastName, TUser.FirstName
```

OR

```
GROUP BY TUser.UserID, TUser_Loyalty.loyalty_ID
ORDER BY TUser.User_ID, MIN(TUser.LastName), MIN(TUser.FirstName)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try one by one and let you know the result. Thank you~~~

Comment: Actually, I don't think anything form the TUser table needs to be aggregated. You are grouping by UserID already. Those fields are uniform across UserID, correct?

Comment: Tried both...still the same error...I think I should use alias name in the order by....

Comment: If you add the LastName and FirstName to the group by then your query should run.

Comment: Tried this already, still didn't work. GROUP BY TUser.UserID, TUser_Loyalty.loyalty_ID, TUser.LastName, TUser.FirstName
  ORDER BY user_ID, loyalty_ID, lastName, firstName

Comment: --> ORDER BY TUser.FirstName, TUser.LastName

Answer (score 0):

Your order by is invalid, Use the alias of the columns instead of the min name's

```
    WHERE (0=1)
    GROUP BY TUser.UserID, TUser_Loyalty.loyalty_ID
    ORDER BY LastName, FirstName, User_ID
```

Also odd...
in order by you have Tuser.user_ID but select shows TUser.userID (no underscore)

order of operation in the SQL has the order by generated after the select, thus column aliases are available.

Comment: Yes, I tried yesterday. It said "Ambiguous column name lastname" or firstname of userid something...

Comment: Can you use a different alias name like aLastName and aFirstName?